# How to fix GCC cross-compiler error on an ARM64 Debian Linux?

Tags: c, linux, x86, kernel, cross-compiling

I Can't build cross compiler to create the kernel for my operating system AmpereOS. My operating system is Debian Linux aarch64.

The operating system is written in x86 and I completed making the bootloader but I can't start working on the kernel because it is giving me an error.

The commmand:

```
../binutils-2.24/configure --target=$TARGET --enable-interwork --enable-multilib --disable-nls --disable-werror --prefix=$PREFIX 2>&1 | tee configure.log
```

The error output:

```
checking build system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu checking host system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu  checking target system type... i386-pc-elf              checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c

checking whether ln works... yes                        checking whether ln -s works... yes

checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed

checking for gawk... gawk

checking for gcc... /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9

checking for C compiler default output file name...     configure: error: in `/tmp/src/binutils-build':

configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

See `config.log' for more details.
```

Operating System: Debian Linux.
Architecture: aarch64

First I Used This Commands:

```
export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9

export LD=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9

export PREFIX="/usr/local/i386elfgcc"

export TARGET=i386-elf

export PATH="$PREFIX/bin:$PATH"

mkdir /tmp/src

cd /tmp/src

curl -O http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.24.tar.gz # If the link 404's, look for a more recent version

tar xf binutils-2.24.tar.gz

mkdir binutils-build

cd binutils-build

../binutils-2.24/configure --target=$TARGET --enable-interwork --enable-multilib --disable-nls --disable-werror --prefix=$PREFIX 2>&1 | tee configure.log

make all install 2>&1 | tee make.log

cd /tmp/src

curl -O https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.9.1/gcc-4.9.1.tar.bz2

tar xf gcc-4.9.1.tar.bz2

mkdir gcc-build

cd gcc-build

../gcc-4.9.1/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --disable-nls --disable-libssp --enable-languages=c --without-headers

make all-gcc 

make all-target-libgcc 

make install-gcc 

make install-target-libgcc
```

The output:

```
checking build system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu checking host system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu  checking target system type... i386-pc-elf              checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c

checking whether ln works... yes                        checking whether ln -s works... yes

checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed

checking for gawk... gawk

checking for gcc... /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9

checking for C compiler default output file name...     configure: error: in `/tmp/src/binutils-build':

configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

See `config.log' for more details.
```

I don't know why is it occuring and how to fix it. Please help.

Comment: Have you looked in `config.log` for more details?

Comment: @SteveFriedl yes I did check the `config.log` and I found this on core tests on config.log:
../binutils-2.41/configure: line 4570: /usr/local/bin/g>
configure:4572: $? = 127
configure:4610: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| int
| main ()
| {
|

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community it's telling me that it's has a problem in `/tmp/src/binutils-build` and C cannot create executables but I don't know what's causing the problem. I even checked the `config.log`. I can't find what's the reason that's causing the issue. I want to know what's causing the problem and fix it.